# unable to log in to user with encrypted home directory

Tags: login, encryption

I made some changes to ~/.pam_environment but I made a mistake. There's a problem with the file syntax now and I can't log in. My home directory is encrypted and I don't have a backup user account to use. I've done some research on mounting it from a Live CD, but it seems to be read only.

Is there a way to force it to skip that file or to mount the file system in read/write mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"That file" (`~/.pam_environment`) is unavailable until you mount and decrypt you8r home directory!

Once you've booted a Live CD, you can gain read/write access with `mount -o remount,rw <device>` command, then follow [these instructions](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/recover-your-encrypted-private-directory-using-ecryptfs-recover-private.html).